How to add generics for each attributy when calling factory function?
I have a function defineRequestAxiosFactory looks like:
type DefineRequestReturns<Options = any> = {
  [K in keyof Options]: Options[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any
    ? Options[K]
    : <Req = any, Res = any>(params: Req, config: AxiosRequestConfig<Req>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<Res, any>>
}

function defineRequestAxiosFactory(request: AxiosInstance) {
  return <T>(options: T) => {
    const result: Record<string, any> = {}
    // ...
    return result as DefineRequestReturns<T>
  }
}

It is used like:
const defineRequest = defineRequestAxiosFactory(axiosInstance)

const api = defineRequest({
  getUser: '/user/list',
})

const resGet = await api.getUser({ id: 1 }, {
  // ...axios instance config
})

How could I add generics for each attributy?
I want it looks like:
const api = defineRequest<{
  getUser: {
    params: { id: number },
    return: { name: string }
  }
}>({
  getUser: '/user/list',
  otherReq: '/other'
})

const resGet = await api.getUser({ id: 1 })
console.log(resGet.name)

I have tried:
interface CustomTypeItem {
  params?: any
  return?: any
}

export type DefineRequestReturns<CustomType extends { [key in keyof Options]?: CustomTypeItem } = object, Options = any> = {
  [K in keyof Options]: Options[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any
    ? Options[K]
    : CustomType[K] extends CustomTypeItem
      ? (params: CustomType[K]['params'], config?: AxiosRequestConfig<CustomType[K]['params']>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<CustomType[K]['return'], any>>
      : <Req = any, Res = any>(params: Req, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<Req>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<Res, any>>
}

// defineRequest type, skip some details.
const defineRequest = <CustomType extends { [key in keyof T]?: CustomTypeItem } = object, T extends DefineRequestOptions = DefineRequestOptions>(options: T) => {...}

But type T have no automatic derivation.

Does this approach work for you? If so, I'll be happy to write up an answer.
